# Do we need to change app_password property if the authentication endpoint is hosted within the product as per the product-level-security-guidelines/

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

This is a general question regarding whether we need to change app_password property if the authentication endpoint is hosted within the product as mentioned in the https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.11.0/administer/product-level-security-guidelines/Configuring client authentication

The doc states that changes are required when the authentication endpoint is hosted externally. Can you share recommendation when it is not hosted externally
Note: We are using Identity Server v5.11

Answer (score 1):

It is always recommended to change the `app_password` as the default password is known to everyone. The `app_username` & `app_password` is used to facilitate some backchannel calls that needed administrative privileges. However, if it is not changed, anyone could use the `app_username` & `app_password` to access endpoints in the authentication & recovery portals. Since your not hosting externally directly changing  `app_password` in the `<IS_HOME>/repository/conf/deployment.toml` would do.

The better approach is to change `app_password` and use a proxy to only expose needed endpoints from authentication & recovery portals.